# PHP preg_match with regex: only single hyphens and spaces between words continue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I was trying to write an regex that allows single hyphens and single spaces only within words but not at the beginning or at the end of the words.

I thought I have this sorted from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928472/php-preg-match-with-regular-expression-only-single-hyphens-and-spaces-between-wo) I got yesterday, but I just realised there is small error which I don't quite understand,

Why it won't accept the inputs like,

```
'forum-category-b forum-category-a'
'forum-category-b Counter-terrorism'
'forum-category-a Preventing'
'forum-category-a Preventing Violent'
'forum-category-a International-Research-and-Publications'
'International-Research-and-Publications forum-category-b forum-category-a'
```

but it takes,

```
'forum-category-b'
'Counter-terrorism forum-category-a'
'Preventing forum-category-a'
'Preventing Violent forum-category-a'
'International-Research-and-Publications forum-category-b'
```

Why is that? How can I fix it? It Below is the regex with the initial test, but ideally it should accept all the combination inputs above,

```
$aWords = array(
    'a',
    '---stack---over---flow---',
    '   stack    over    flow',
    'stack-over-flow',
    'stack over flow',
    'stacoverflow'
);

foreach($aWords as $sWord) {
    if (preg_match('/^(\w+([\s-]\w+)?)+$/', $sWord)) {
        echo 'pass: ' . $sWord . "\n";
    } else {
        echo 'fail: ' . $sWord . "\n";
    }
}
```

accept/ to reject the input like these below,

```
---stack---over---flow---
stack-over-flow- stack-over-flow2
   stack    over    flow
```

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to know about the `\p{Pd}` property for Dash Punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern does not do what you want. Let's break it apart:

```
^(\w+([\s-]\w+)?)+$
```

It matches strings that consist solely of one or more sequences of the pattern:

```
\w+([\s-]\w+)?
```

...which is a sequence of word characters, followed optionally by one other sequence of word characters, separated by one space or dash character.

In other words, your pattern searches for strings like:

```
xxx-xxxyyy-yyyzzz zzz
```

...but you intent to write a pattern that would find:

```
xxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx yyy
```

---

In your examples, this one is matched:

```
Counter-terrorism forum-category-a
```

...but it is interpreted as the following sequence:

```
(Counter(-terroris)) (m( foru)) (m(-categor) (y(-a))
```

As you can see, the pattern did not really find the words you are looking for.

This example is not matched:

```
forum-category-a Preventing Violent
```

...since the pattern cannot form groups of "word characters, space-or-dash, word-characters" when it encounters a single word character followed by space or dash:

```
(forum(-categor)) (y(-a)) <Mismatch: Found " " but expected "\w">
```

If you would add another character to "forum-category-a", say "forum-category-ax", it would match again, since it could split at the "ax":

```
(forum(-categor)) (y(-a)) (x( Preventin)) (g( Violent))
```

---

What you are actually interested in is a pattern like

```
^(\w+(-\w+)*)(\s\w+(-\w+)*)*$
```

...which would find a sequence of words that may contain dashes, separated by spaces:

```
(forum(-category)(-a)) ( Preventing) ( Violent)
```

---

By the way, I tested this using a Python script, and while trying to match your pattern against the example string "International-Research-and-Publications forum-category-b forum-category-a", the regular expression engine seemed to run into an infinite loop...

```
import re
expr = re.compile(r'^(\w+([\s-]\w+)?)+$')
expr.match('International-Research-and-Publications forum-category-b forum-category-a')
```

Comment: thanks you so much! you have saved my life!! I added in another line of regex which only take alphabet number characters only - /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/ lol thanks!

Comment: thanks for the your edit. awww Python!!! It works fine with PHP. How come!??? Which language has the bug!? sign.... I guess this regex is incorrect - /^(\w+([\s-]\w+)?)+$/ !

Comment: I guess it has nothing to do with Python vs PHP but it is an implementation detail of the regular expression engines in use.  Maybe PHP's PCRE engine has a stricter circle detection than Python's SRE engine.  The problem is in fact your regex pattern,  see also http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 0):

the part of your pattern `([\s-]\w+)?` is the issue. It's only allowing for one repetition (the trailing `?`). Try changing the last `?` to `*` and see if that helps.

Nope, I still believe that's the problem. The original pattern is looking for "word" or "word[space_hyphen]word" repeated 1+ times. Which is weird because the pattern should fall within another match. But switching the question mark [worked for me](http://regexr.com?2t2el).

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one answer to this problem:

`/^((?<=\w)[ -]\w|[^ -])+$/`

There is only 1 rule as stated   `\w[ -]\w` and thats it. And its on a **per character basis** granularity, and cannot be anthing else. Add the [^ -] for the rest.